# MIDI library for STM32

Tags: library, midi

I found a few USB / MIDI 'libraries' for STM32.

However, I'm looking for a library that can handle (multiple) MIDI In/Out (DIN5) connectors with STM32 (preferably STM32F4), thus using UART/USART.

I wonder if something is available (to prevent creating it myself while something similar exists), since I cannot imagine I'm the first one doing something with MIDI (DIN5) ports.

I'm looking for something similar as the Fourtyseven Effects MIDI library like on the Arduino: [fourtyseven effects](https://github.com/FortySevenEffects/arduino_midi_library/releases/tag/4.3.1).

Comment: With multiple UARTs running in parallel, you just have to use multiple instances of the library data structures in parallel. (If your library uses global variables, change it appropriately.)

Comment: @CL I understand, but so far I don't know what is a (good) library to use ... I assume the library (if there is one) supports having multiple instances.

Comment: @CL: is this really a good place? I doubt (except you) there are very few people heard even about STM32

Comment: That message is misleading; the first four users voted to close as off topic; only an admin can migrate to softwarerecs. Anyway, this is the only site where this question could be on topic.

Comment: @CL Thanks for the clarification ... I will do a bit more googling, and asking a slightly different question to hopefully get an answer to such ' trivial'  question. Or maybe I was spoiled too much with the Arduino library and going to write my own dedicated software for receiving/transmitting MIDI.

Comment: Consider porting some other library to the STM hardware.

Comment: @CL: I haven't found any UART library related to MIDI. However, I'm thinking of making my own (or at least to be able to use it in my project). I guess afterwards I know how UARTs work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a github repository for something that should do the trick.
https://github.com/TheKikGen/USBMidiKliK4x4

Comment: It looks good, although I reverted back to Arduino for now. But good to know there is a MIDI library.